# Validar que el usuario ingrese únicamente el valor esperado

Tags: c#, validación

estoy desarrollando un programa simple en donde se simule el funcionamiento de un ascensor donde la letra "S" indica que el usuario quiere subir un piso y la letra "B" indica que el usuario quiere bajar un piso. Estoy intentando hacer uso de un bucle do/while para que cuando el usuario ingrese un valor diferente a S o B, salte un error diciendo que la opción es inválida y que por favor intente de nuevo, pero simplemente no consigo que funcione.

Aquí un fragmento de lo que llevo hasta ahora:

```
string userInput;
short floorNumber;

                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine("Bienvenido! \nPara subir un piso digite la letra S, para bajar digite la letra B");
                    Console.Write("Seleccione una opción ==> ");
                    userInput = Console.ReadLine();

                    do
                    {
                        Console.Write("Opción inválida, intente de nuevo ==> ");
                        userInput = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
                    } while (userInput != "S" && userInput != "B");
```

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > Validar que el usuario ingrese únicamente el valor esperado

El método [ToLower](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.tolower?view=netframework-4.8) convierte la cadena a minúscula, es decir, cuando el usuario ingrese la letra `S`, la condición `userInput != "S" && userInput != "B"` se cumplirá y mandará el mensaje de error y esto se debe porqué estás convirtiendo la cadena a minúscula con el [ToLower](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.tolower?view=netframework-4.8).

La solución es usar el método [ToUpper](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.toupper?view=netframework-4.8), esta función convertirá la cadena a mayúscula, es decir, si el usuario ingresa una `b`, la convertirá a `B`.

Solo debes cambiar esta línea:

```
userInput = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
```

Por esta:

```
userInput = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
```

**EDIT:**

Si te das cuenta, este mensaje se imprime primero: `Opción inválida, intente de nuevo ==>` y no debería ser así, ya que ese mensaje solo se debe visualizar al usuario cuando haya escrito una letra que no sea la `S` o la `B`.

Una posible solución sería esta:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string userInput;
        short floorNumber;

        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Bienvenido! \nPara subir un piso digite la letra S, para bajar digite la letra B");
        Console.Write("Seleccione una opción ==> ");
        do
        {
            userInput = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
            if(userInput != "S" && userInput != "B")
                Console.Write("Opción inválida, intente de nuevo ==> ");
            else
                break;
         } while (true);
    }
}
```

Comment: En este caso siempre va a ser un error lo que el usuario vea sin importar que ingrese.

Comment: @CubitoSenpai Ya edité mi respuesta.

Comment: Ahora sí que funciona bien, muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Podrias manejar un **bandera** en tus instancias, yo lo hare un boolean que inicializo en **true**  donde coloco una condicion en la que evaluo el ingreso del usuario y cambio la **bandera** en caso de que lo que ingrese sea diferente a **A** y **B** **(ten en cuenta si el ingreso debe ser en mayuscula o minuscula o en ambos)**, en el caso de que la bandera nunca cambie se saldra del ciclo ya que lo que ingreso el usuario es **correcto**.

**NOTA:** en este caso haces el `Console.ReadLine().ToLower();` lo cual devuelve minusculas por lo que lo valido con las minusculas.

ahora si la **bandera cambia** va a mostrarle el mensaje y a volver a jecutar el ingreso de datos.

```
//instancias
Boolean estado = true;

//ciclo
do
{
  userInput = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
  if (userInput != "s" && userInput != "b")
  {
    estado=false;
  }
  if(estado==false)
  {
    Console.Write("Opción inválida, intente de nuevo ==> ");
  }
} while (estado==false);
```

espero te ayude

Comment: No veo la razon por la que no te funcione la condicion, revisa porfa.

Comment: No funciona porque aunque pongas S, s o B, b siempre te va a decir que la opción es inválida.